Engine control circuit design
I am working on a machine similar to an internal combustion engine. There are three identical stations connected to a common crankshaft. The rods are 6 inches long, the pistons are 4 inches in diameter, the crankshaft throw is 1.5 inches, the machine runs at 120 rpm. At the top and bottom of the stroke there is a 1 inch diameter shaft that needs to be rotated 90 degrees very quickly, in around 20ms. The shaft needs 20 foot pounds of torque to rotate.
I built the prototype, I used a double acting air cylinder for the rotation, triggered by microswitches. The machine ran OK but the air cylinders consume too much power as air compressors are very inefficient. I spent a lot of time trying to do the rotation with electric motors and linear activators. Nothing worked because the methods were either too slow or consumed too much power.
I next looked at solenoids and found some that would probably work. The solenoids I looked at were push-pull, can generate the right amount of force, they run an 24VDC and consume some 100 watts of power. I would like to use capacitors to power the solenoids but my experience with capacitors is very limited.
At 120 rpm one revolution takes .5 seconds. In one revolution the solenoid needs to activate twice. Is that even possible with capacitors? I could activate the rotation at the top and bottom of the stroke independently to allow the capacitors to charge. What size of capacitor would I need?

I'm not sure I completely understood the setup, but some ballpark calculations seem to point out a flaw in the solenoid approach.
20ft-lb of torque is 28Nm. The energy (work) \$W\$ required to apply 28Nm of torque through an angle of 90° is:
$$ W = 28Nm \times \frac{\pi}{2} = 44J $$
This energy must be delivered during an interval of \$t=20ms\$, during which power \$P\$ will be:
$$ P = \frac{W}{t} = \frac{44J}{20ms} = 2.2kW $$
Already this rules out your solenoid solution, because those solenoids consume 100W, and even if they were 100% efficient in converting that electrical energy to mechanical rotation, they can't deliver energy faster than they receive it. To deliver 44J of mechanical energy would take much longer than 20ms:
$$ \frac{44J}{100W} = 440ms $$
Those solenoids may be capable of applying sufficient static force, but they are not able to maintain that force as they travel over the required distance.
From the perspective of conservation of energy alone, whatever solution you come up with must provide 44J per actuation. Peak power will be 2.2kW over 20ms, and probably quite a bit more than that to account for inefficiency of each element in the chain between the energy source (such as a battery or a pneumatic reservoir) and the mechanical actuator.
It's true that capacitors and pneumatic reservoirs can store that energy, which will incur lower average input power, but I think your main concern are those 2.2kW in a short burst.

Thank you Simon. Actually the torque required profile is a sine wave, it is 0 at 0 degrees, 20 ft-lbs at 45 degrees and 0 at 90 degrees.  I could possibly extend the to to 40ms.  Maybe the reason I have so much trouble is that it can not be done? Thank you again.

@BillKaltenekker That changes things a bit; the average value of a half-period of a sinusoid is 0.64, so total energy would be $0.64\times 44J=28J$, which over 40ms is an average power of 700W. Peak power depends on the velocity profile of the motion, but will probably be over 1kW. It can be done, of course, but those numbers are daunting! Sorry the news isn't better.

Thank you very much Simon
